# Understanding a passage from 銀河鉄道の夜

Tags: verbs, readings, parsing, ある, てある

I was reading the short novel 銀河鉄道の夜 by 宮沢賢治 and, although it's not super hard, I stumble upon on this sentence (as usual I post the whole paragraph for context):

> 家へは帰らずジョバンニが町を三つ曲って**ある**大きな活版処にはいってすぐ入口の計算台に居ただぶだぶの白いシャツを着た人におじぎをしてジョバンニは靴をぬいで上りますと、突き当りの大きな扉をあけました。

Now, I don't understand if ある is part of the verb 曲って, so we have 曲ってある that modify the 活版 noun, or it's a simple ～て verb and only ある modify 活版.

Comment: Could you please check your novel's sentence carefully for inline furigana?

Comment: @user3856370 What do you mean with "inline furigana"? I paste and copy the sentence without add or remove anything. Also it's not a problem of reading.

Comment: What I meant was that it looks like you've copied and pasted a sentence that had furigana and that furigana has appeared in your sentence along with the kanji. For example "靴" pasted to "靴くつ". It looks like @jogloran has corrected it for you. See his edit if you're still confused.

Comment: It was @naruto who edited the post to fix the furigana, not me.

Comment: @user3856370 Now that I read the original paragraph, you're right.  It was my fault.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both interpretations are possible, but that shouldn't affect the meaning. Either way, you find 活版処 after turning three corners.

That said, 曲がってある (of first interpretation) is not really idiomatic. 角を曲がってある喫茶店 is odd. It should be 角を曲がったところにある喫茶店.

So, more likely is the second interpretation where only ある modifies the 活版処 (*a certain printer's (place)*).