# What do "。" and "、" mean?

Tags: meaning, translation

I was browsing and found [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/99799/33560).

At the end of the following text (from *"Night on the Galactic Railroad"*):

> 家へは帰らずジョバンニが町を三つ曲って**ある**大きな活版処にはいってすぐ入口の計算台に居ただぶだぶの白いシャツを着た人におじぎをしてジョバンニは靴をぬいで上りますと、突き当りの大きな扉をあけました。

There is this character:

> 。

And towards the end of the text:

> ... "、突き当りの大きな扉をあけました。"

There is this character:

> 、

Am I correct in assuming that this is punctuation? **I.E:** a full-stop (period in en-US) and a comma, respectively?

If not, what do they mean?

Comment: Yes you are right. 、is a Japanese comma (読点 in Japanese), and 。 is a Japanese period (句点 in Japanese).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first character is a full stop:

> Source: Wikipedia, [Japanese Punctuation: Full Stop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_punctuation#Full_stop)

The second character is a comma:

> Source: Wikipedia, [Japanese Punctuation: Comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_punctuation#Comma)

See: [Japanese Punctuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_punctuation) (Wikipedia).